# docker push: всегда получаю ошибку authentication required

Tags: docker

я делаю свой приватный docker registry.

Для начала я просто поднял его в докере, как [написано](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-your-own-registry-2/) на их сайте.

```
  docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Попробовал - всё локально работает.

Начал навешивать аутентификацию.

Нашел довольно понятную [статью](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-secure-private-docker-registry/) и "[краткий ответ на вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033624/how-to-set-username-and-password-for-our-own-docker-private-registry)" на стековерфлоу.

скомпилировалв, получил команду для запуска такого docker registry

```
    docker run -d \
      -p 5000:5000 \
      --restart=always \
      --name registry \
      -v /DData/auth:/auth \
      -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
      -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
      -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
       registry:2
```

при этом я заранее создал файл паролей в /DData/auth командой

```
    htpasswd -Bc htpasswd konst
```

Потом я начинаю пробовать команду `docker login`, получаю "по башке" загадочнейшим сообщением `"Message: Remote error from secret service:"`

Читаю про `config.json`, выхожу на [тред на cтековерфлоу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151833/cannot-login-to-docker-account) и у меня срабатывает магия (а по другому это назвать нельзя)

```
    sudo apt install gnupg2 pass
```

- и после этого docker загадочным образом начинает логиниться!

для справки: я залез в файл ~/.docker/config.json

и увидел, что там засейвлен какой то пароль, скоре всего, мой:

```
    {                                                              
            "auths": {                                             
                    "docker.junecat.ru": {                         
                            "auth": "a29uc3*********ZmGF1bX43"     
                    }                                              
            }                                                      
    }
```

Потом я начинаю химичить с nginx'ом:

создаю виртуальный хост, настраиваю nginx в режиме proxy при помощи такого конфига:

```
    # config for Docker
    server {

        server_name docker.junecat.ru www.docker.junecat.ru;

    location / {
              #auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
              #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
              proxy_redirect          http://192.168.0.10:5000/  /;
              proxy_pass_header       Server;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
              proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
              proxy_connect_timeout   5;
              proxy_read_timeout      240;
              proxy_intercept_errors  on;

              proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.10:5000/;
              client_max_body_size 5000M;
        }
    }
```

получаю на него lentsencrypt'овский сертификат

```
    sudo certbot --nginx -d docker.junecat.ru -d www.docker.junecat.ru
```

Казалось бы, всё хорошо: снаружи по запросу

`https://docker.junecat.ru/v2/_catalog`

я сначала получаю запрос на base auth, а потом, когад аутентификация проведена, вижу пустой список образов:

`{"repositories":[]}`

Но в само конце меня поджидает большой облом:

я беру hello-world образ, тэгаю его для заливки на свой сервер

```
    docker run hello-world
    docker tag hello-world docker.junecat.ru/hello-world
```

и пытаюсь залить (перед этим я сделал docker login и у меня аутентификация - сохранена)

```
    docker push docker.junecat.ru/hello-world
```

получаю ошибку authentication required

и всегда, на любую попытку заливки я получаю эту ошибку.

[image: authentication required]

*Никакого продвижения после копания в сети.*

я уже убил на это чертову уйму времени, и хотел бы довести дело до конца.

Нет и у кого то предположений, как это можно победить?

Заранее **большое спасибо**!

**Дополнение**

Самое смешное. Жить то как то надо... взял [инструкцию](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-18-04) с сайта DO, который я вобще то нежно люблю. Сделал по инструкции, не думая, вроде бы, то же саое. *Работает!*

Не могу понять пока что, где же я в первый раз накосячил... разве что nginx по разному сконфигурирован?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут сразу две проблемы.

Первая заключается в том, что proxy_pass передаёт только те заголовки, которые явно указаны в конфигурации. Вы в своей конфигурации не передаёте заголовок `Authorization`, поэтому к registry запрос приходит неавторизованным.

Ладно, не проблема, можно добавить

```
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
```

После этого nginx начинает передавать-таки креденшиалы пользователя.

Но этого, увы, недостаточно, наступают вторые грабли.

Как [написано в документации](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#native-basic-auth)

> **Warning**: You **cannot** use authentication with authentication schemes that send credentials as clear text. You must configure TLS first for authentication to work.

То есть нужно одновременно с `REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH` задавать `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE` и `REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY`. *правда, этот тезис противоречит вашему опыту с DO - в той инструкции нет никаких проблем с передачей креденшиалов по незащищённому каналу, верну?*

Я посмотрел на это дело, подумал: на какое имя делать сертификат?

- (а) Если самоподписной `localhost`, то `nginx` может заколдобиться, нужно прописывать запрет на проверку сертификата
- (б) Если для доменного имени моего реестра, то ... из этого немедленно следует та-а-акой геморрой с обновлением этого сертификата на внутреннем сервере, который не виден из внешней сети.

Поэтому я сразу плюнул и сделал по [мануалу на сайте docker-а](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/):

- реестр работает без шифрования и без аутентификации

  ```bash
  docker run -itd -p 5000:5000 --name registry -v /var/lib/registry:/var/lib/registry  --restart always   registry:2
  ```
- все сертификаты и пароли хранятся в `nginx`. Сертбот автоматически обновляет сертификаты.

Оно сразу заработало.

Единственный геморрой - как добавлять пользователей. У нас этим занимается специально обученная девочка, у которой есть инструкция о добавлении пользователей в Gitlab, Mattermost, Google Suite. Но на инструкции

```bash
ssh frontend htpasswd /etc/nginx/auth/docker_registry.htpasswd -cb <user_name> <user_pwd>
```

её глаза необратимо стекленеют...

Comment: Однако, судя по всему, придётся переделывать. Хочется прикрутить аутентификацию через Gitlab и разграничить права доступа к образам, какие кому можно скачивать: те, которые с исходниками внутри - только для команды, а те, которые с бинарниками - для заказчика.

Comment: Pak Uula - огромное спасибо, Ваши ответы на мои вопросы - это всегда предел совершенства и россыпь не защищенных копирайтом идей! я только сейчас за метил ответ, и жалею, что не могу поставить за него сразу много плюсов. И еще: когда я делал по инструкции с DO - я взял сертификат с летсэнкрипта